# I want to complete the quiz with variables or lists without Python input

Tags: python

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 10)
    
player_name = input("Hello, What's your name?")
number_of_guesses = 0
print('okay! '+ player_name+ ' I am Guessing a number between 1 and 10:')
    
while number_of_guesses < 5:
guess = int(input())
number_of_guesses += 1`
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high')
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number:
    print('You guessed the number in ' + str(number_of_guesses) + ' tries!')
else:
    print('You did not guess the number, The number was ' + str(number))
```

Above is the normal Python Numberguessing game code.

But I want to make a quiz game using variables or lists without input.

Like using input

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 10)

list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

number_of_guesses = 0
print(' I am Guessing a number between 1 and 10:')

while number_of_guesses < 3:

    number_of_guesses += 1
    if list < number:
        print('Your guess is too low')
    if list  > number:
        print('Your guess is too high')
    if list  == number:
        break
if list  == number:
  print('축하합니다! 당신은 {}번의 시도만에 정답을 맞췄습니다.!'.format(number_of_guesses))                  
else:
  print('아쉽지만 정답을 맞추지 못했네요. 정답은 {} 이었습니다. 다시 도전해보세요!'.format(number))
```

I tried to make it using a list or variable, but I failed.
Help me please.**

Comment: nit: don't use `list` as variable name. you cannot compare `list[int]` with `int`. can you elaborate more by sharing example what is the expected input and output for a case ?

Comment: This is a double of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74596571/i-want-to-make-a-guess-the-number-code-without-input please make clear what you want and delete on or the other. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to make a Guess the number code without input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74596571/i-want-to-make-a-guess-the-number-code-without-input)

Answer (score 1):

See my code .

**Code-:**

```
import random
lis=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10]
print('I am Guessing a number between 1 and 10:\n')
for number in lis:
    number_of_guesses = 0
    while number_of_guesses<3:
        guess_number=random.randint(1,10)
        if number<guess_number:
            number_of_guesses+=1
            print('Your guess number is high '+str(guess_number))
        elif number>guess_number:
            number_of_guesses+=1
            print('Your guess number is low '+str(guess_number))
        else:
            print("You guess Right The number is: "+str(guess_number)+"\nNumber of guess taken "+str(number_of_guesses+1))
            break
    if number_of_guesses==3:
        print("Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct")
```

**Output:-**

```
I am Guessing a number between 1 and 10:

Your guess number is high 5
Your guess number is high 10
Your guess number is high 9
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
Your guess number is high 4
Your guess number is high 7
Your guess number is high 3
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
Your guess number is high 5
Your guess number is high 5
Your guess number is high 10
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
Your guess number is high 5
Your guess number is high 8
Your guess number is high 6
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
Your guess number is high 7
Your guess number is low 1
You guess Right The number is: 5
Number of guess taken 3
Your guess number is low 5
Your guess number is high 9
Your guess number is low 3
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
Your guess number is high 10
Your guess number is low 3
Your guess number is low 5
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
Your guess number is low 6
Your guess number is low 5
Your guess number is low 7
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number
```

**Please give the feedback if this helps to you..!**

Comment: No, it's not that I'm guessing the answer. It's just a self-repeating problem.  
I want to make a code to answer questions without input. Using lists and variables,

Comment: can you more elaborate your question with Example [like input and output of the example]. I think than i can contribute in your question.