# I want to make a Guess the number code without input

Tags: python

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 10)

player_name = "doo"
number_of_guesses = 0
print('I\'m glad to meet you! {} \nLet\'s play a game with you, I will think a number between 1 and 10 then you will guess, alright? \nDon\'t forget! You have only 3 chances so guess:'.format(player_name))

while number_of_guesses < 3:
    guess = int(input())
    number_of_guesses += 1
    if guess < number:
        print('Your estimate is too low, go up a little!')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your estimate is too high, go down a bit!')
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number:
    print( 'Congratulations {}, you guessed the number in {} tries!'.format(player_name, number_of_guesses))
else:
    print('Close but no cigar, you couldn\'t guess the number. \nWell, the number was {}.'.format(number))
```

**Above is the Guess the number project using input.**

**I want to make it without input.**

**Can't we use a list or variable to make it?**

**So I tried.**

```
import random
list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10]
print('I am Guessing a number between 1 and 10:\n')
for number in lis:
    number_of_guesses = 0
    while number_of_guesses<3:
        guess_number=random.randint(1,10)
        if number<guess_number:
            number_of_guesses+=1
            print('Your guess number is high '+str(guess_number))
        elif number>guess_number:
            number_of_guesses+=1
            print('Your guess number is low '+str(guess_number))
        else:
            print("You guess Right The number is: "+str(guess_number)+"\nNumber of guess taken "+str(number_of_guesses+1))
            break
    if number_of_guesses==3:
        print("Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct")
```

**Failed to create Guess the number code without input.**

**Help me.**

Comment: If you don't want to accept the user input, then how will you know that it's too high or too low. or if it's even right? What is your workflow?

Comment: What do you mean by *Failed to create Guess the number code without input.*? What exactly failed when you tried to run your second block of code? did you get an error, or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Can't you use variables or lists without input to make it seem like there is input?

Comment: This is a double of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74596571/i-want-to-make-a-guess-the-number-code-without-input please make clear what you want and delete on or the other. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you want to "test" your program and therefore use a list of inputs instead of real user inputs?

However, you made a mistake in line 6
`for number in lis:` -> `for number in list:`

If I change this line it gives me this output. Is that what you wanted?

```
I am Guessing a number between 1 and 10:

Your guess number is high 9
Your guess number is high 7
Your guess number is high 8
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
You guess Right The number is: 2
Number of guess taken 1
Your guess number is high 10
You guess Right The number is: 3
Number of guess taken 2
Your guess number is high 9
Your guess number is low 1
Your guess number is low 2
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
Your guess number is low 2
Your guess number is high 10
Your guess number is high 6
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
You guess Right The number is: 8
Number of guess taken 1
Your guess number is high 10
Your guess number is low 7
Your guess number is low 2
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
Your guess number is low 7
Your guess number is low 8
Your guess number is low 8
Sorry your chances of guessing is over! You can not guess the number correct
```

Comment: I have also shared the same thing as yours in his previous question. don't know why he not giving any feedback or what he wants in his solution. My solution ..! https://stackoverflow.com/a/74569131/20172954

Comment: No, it's not that I'm guessing the answer. It's just a self-repeating problem.

Comment: I want to make a code to answer questions without input.
Using lists and variables,

Comment: @YashMehta Thanks for noticing me. I do not know either.

Comment: @dodo87 please make clear what you want and delete on or the other. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help